# Server doesn't receive form from frontend requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

Im running a server in backend using (nodejs and express), in the frontend im using reactJs and axios to send the requests to the server, my issue here it is that sometimes when Im in the website in afk for sometime and then click a button to send the request, the request isnt sended until a reload the website (normally if I am active in the website, all the requests get to the server) if i go away 5 minutes of the website and come back, the buttons doesn't work, or I click them and when I reload the website, the request is sent. Extra data: in the server I'm using morgen to check if the request are getting to the server (they aren't getting when I'm afk in the website), also, this is my code to send the request using axios:

```
 const update = () => {
    Axios.get(API_BASE + "/update", {
      params: {
        cacheBust: new Date().getTime()
      },
      withCredentials: true
    });
  }
```

Also I used that variable "cacheBust" to prevent the browser to save the request into the cache and not sending it. More info, in the network tab (inspect element) it says that the request is being sent but pending, until I reload the website that morgen detects the requests in the backend and the network tab in the frontend updates to status 200.

Well, I tried using Jquery and Fetch, having the same problem. also, changing browser.